# ionic app cannot connect cors enabled server with $http

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to build a mobile app with ionic framework. When my application tries to connect  server to get json ( server is web api and cors is enabled)  it just returns 404 on genymotion and real device. But when I run application in browser with `ionic serve` everything work fine.

I am pretty sure CORS is functional. Here response header I got while application working in browser.

**Response**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:395
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 May 2015 20:24:04 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**Request** :

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:*******:14400
Origin:http://192.168.0.28:8100
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://192.168.0.28:8100/
```

Config.xml has  `<access origin="*"/>` this line in configuration

in my app.js I removed X-Requested-With headers for all http calls.

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];  
    }
])
```

I simple use get requests to server in my factory classes.

```
$http.get(serverPath + "/api/mobilerest/mainPage");
```

When I run application in Genymode or real device, response is 404 and statusText is 'not found'. I am pretty sure web api is working, the cause for this behaviour is in ionic based apps, my app is local file and protocol  is file:/// so Origin header is null the in request, then server returns 404. I also tried a local file without any server I get the same error like in application.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:server:14400
Origin:null
Pragma:no-cache
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) seems to be "mandatory" at present.

**install it :**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

**configure config.xml**

You can keep your current setup with * or change for more restrictive rules

**add a html policy**
on index.html, you shall add a Policy also.
To authorise everything, here it is :

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
 'unsafe-eval'"
```

Comment: Thank you @aorfevre it worked. But why I couldnt find this information on anywhere :)

Comment: Again thank you for sharing @aorfevre. Like adt I could not figure why it was working in the browser and not on my device

Comment: This worked for me too. I am not sure why is this not added to any documentation. It has been discussed in some forums.

Comment: Thanks Dude for this help :)

Comment: I came across the same issue from iOS emulator. I did have whitelist plugin installed and the html policy set on index.html. After I saw this post I removed the plugin and reinstalled it. That fixed my problem thanks!!!

Comment: I have some issue with Capacitor! Any ideas?

Comment: I assume that it is better for you to make a proper question for that @El7or as it may be linked to Capacitor precisly.

Answer (score -1):

**you can just go into config .xml file and edit this line**

```
<access origin="*://*/*" />
```

> and you can call any data with out intruption of CORS in console
>   thank you plz apply this code your ionic app