# Android store app not showing images - fine in development

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I thought I had my problem solved when I saw this SO answer

[Issue with Android Hybid app to display remote image with Ionic framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912773/issue-with-android-hybid-app-to-display-remote-image-with-ionic-framework)

This works in development and I deployed this APK to the store as my app was effectively broken and when it's downloaded from the Play store it doesn't work. No images from external URLs are down.

I have done in Config.xml:

`<access origin="*"/>`

`<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />`

and the following in `index.html`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Additionally it would be great to know how to simulate this is testing as if this was to happen with the Apple App Store we would be in trouble.

==EDIT==

So I have pinned this down to the release APK. The debug works perfectly however when I install the release APK manually then I am unable to view the images from external sources. Obviously I am unable to debug this version either?

Answer (score 0):

have you install the cordova whitelist plugin ? 
See my explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135532/3687474

Or install the de version :
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Yes i'm pretty certain - just tried it again using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` and i'm getting a `404` I wonder if thats what happened before and I thought I had added it...

Comment: `Failed to find the bower component "cordova-plugin-whitelist".`

Comment: this is strange, I do hve it installed properly => cordova-plugin-whitelist Try to install the dev version (see my post)

Comment: I have added command to install the dev version of whitelist plugin

Comment: `npm ERR! addLocal Could not install github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
Error: ENOENT, stat 'github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist'
`

Comment: this command is not correct, Stackoverflow automaticly hide "https://" see my post edited , I paste it with the https://

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78023/discussion-between-taylorsuk-and-aorfevre).

Answer (score 0):

I had to run:

`npm install -g cordova`

then run `ionic platform remove android` followed by adding it again and then adding the whitelist plugin as described above:

`ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`