# Ionic - no internet connection

Tags: android, ionic-framework

We are building a android application using Ionic (+Cordova).

It all works in my browser, but when I build it and run the .apk this happens:

External images won't appear, and embeded google maps remain empty. The following code at our index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">

          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <div class="main" role="main">

                <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" alt="no image" />

                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d635472.0298105411!2d5.1189025!3d51.525825749999996!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1432033961557" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
            </div>
          </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

In the config.xml we've created the following lines just after the closing tag of :

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Comment: whats your internet permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Android Hybid app to display remote image with Ionic framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912773/issue-with-android-hybid-app-to-display-remote-image-with-ionic-framework)

Comment: @mahdi pishguy do you mean this line?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: You need to add the whitelist plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132885/ionic-app-cannot-connect-cors-enabled-server-with-http/30135532#30135532

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your manifest to allow your app to use internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you are using cordova 5 (Android platform version 4.0.0) then you should include the whitelist plugin and also the new [content security policy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy) meta tag to allow google maps api to load like this (on the top of your html file along with the rest meta tags):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://fonts.googleapis.com/;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://*.googleapis.com
 http://maps.gstatic.com;">
```

EDIT:
Check also your config.xml what access you give:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

for instance to allow all connections

If it doesn't work please check your logs and post any errors.

Comment: I had the same issue, adding `android.permission.INTERNET` did the trick, I have no idea how the permission was removed !

Answer (score 0):

No forget add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

into application tag on AndroidManifest.xml

After test into real device.