# allow navigation app ionic failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In my application was failing several connections to my webservice, I found the way to solve it through a plugin, `Cordova-plugin-whitelist`. However, adding this plugin I had some problems with google maps and not loaded.

my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Error :

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'google.maps.event.addDomListener')
```

Removing the `meta` parameter, all the maps loaded correctly.

Comment: check my answer on this SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324899/ionic-no-internet-connection/30325189#30325189)

Comment: I wouldn't want to work ... but I have to!

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowing to load resources from the same origin: `self`.

```
script-src 'self'
```

You might want to read what the [cordova plugin white](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy) list has defined.
Another source of information can be found [here](http://content-security-policy.com/) where every single chunk of value is explained in a very clear way.

I would change your `meta` allowing a few urls to be loaded. Try to change it like this. It should work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ https://mts1.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Other interesting articles on the topic can be found [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5) and [here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/).

Comment: This does not work for me, I get these errors: Error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new google.maps.Map(el, {})') and <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="14" id="map_views" data-tap-disabled="true" style="display: block;"> ionic.bundle.js:20299
Error: undefined is not a valid argument for 'instanceof' (evaluating 'markerOptions.position instanceof google.maps.LatLng')