# Google Maps problems with android(Cordova/Ionic )

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I follow all steps from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkNKoSO9X60) and all works fine in the browser, but when I try to run in my device the map is not show.

Can you share the github of any functional example? I try many tutorials and I can't show the map in the device.

Maybe I have any other problem(maybe with the device). If you share any functional code with me I can try run this code in my device and confirm if the problem is my device or my code.

Other Questions...What's is the Key api who i should use for cordova projects, Android o browser key?

I will be very grateful with you, please help me

Comment: if you have cordova 5.0.0 then you need the cordova-plugin-whitelist. See my reply here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30135532/3687474